# Calling a spring Rest Controller from a Web Controller

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

We are trying to build an application using spring-boot-web and thyme-leaf. This is what we have got as of now.

- **The REST Layer:-** These are the `@RestController` APIs which exposes data to the external world.
- **The Web Layer:-** These are the `@Controller` endpoints which deal with the UI part of the application. Any request from UI will come here and from this layer, we are planning to call the rest layer.

Is this a correct approach, if yes how ideally I should call the rest layer from the web layer? One Idea could be using a REST Template to call the REST layer and treat it as a segregated API, but I am not sure if that is the right way to do it. Feels like one extra network call to me.

Comment: Why would you call a `@RestController` from a `@Controller`? Also, "The Web Layer" is a very misleading name for your controllers.

Comment: These days, in a lot of cases it's more common to write the HTML frontend as a JavaScript application that calls the same REST endpoints over HTTP.

Comment: @chrylis The Idea is we are not sure if we are doing a UI heavy project to keep a different Frontend application. That is the reason we are going ahead with the application which has a simple UI as well.

Comment: @Kayaman That's where I have the question, The idea is I want to keep the REST Layer to be independent of the UI. The submit form request will come to another controller which is just handling UI, not the REST APIs. That's why I need to call the Rest Controller from UI Controller.

Comment: That's why I have posted this question wanted some Idea about the same. How do we keep the UI and REST part separate?

Comment: If you're not going to write a JS frontend like chrylis was talking about, then the UI and REST stay separate by default. You're the one who wants to connect the controllers with the rest api, which doesn't make any sense. You might want to get someone else to design it, if you don't have experience with regular MVC web applications.

Comment: This isn't actually quite as crazy as it sounds, @Kayaman, and I've done something similar. While I don't recommend this approach to someone who doesn't yet have the experience to make judgments regarding tier boundaries, it's entirely possible to inject the REST controllers (which carry all Web logic and return POJOs) into the HTML controllers (which make delegate calls and then assemble `ModelAndView` responses).

Comment: @chrylis well I wouldn't create an unnecessary dependency between the two. I didn't say it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Controller doesn't need to call Rest controller.
Create common service used by Controller and Rest Controller, If you need rest service as well as UI.

Answer (score 1):

1. You only need @RestController in your application architecture, if you want to call that endpoint from a client using AJAX (jquery, javascript, React, Angular).
2. If your pages are being rendered from server side and FORMs are submitted without AJAX then you only need @Controller
3. To separate your business logic from controllers (web controller as you said), you can introduce the @Service layer that you can call from your @Controller.